# Desactivar devices en R stduio

Tags: r, rstudio

Un problema algo tonto
Sucede que cada vez que trato de graficar la imagen se despliega en una ventana (devices) al lado y no en R studio, he tratado con

```
dev.off()
```

para desactivarla y poder graficar dentro de plots en R studio pero no funciona. He buscado el problema en internet pero solo encuentro como abrir mas de esas ventanas con

```
X11()
```

Quiero que ya deje de hacer eso y grafique en el lateral derecho como siempre. ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Prueba correr esto `options(device = "RStudioGD")` ¿lo soluciona?

Comment: noo, ahora ya no gráfica nada y da este error: Error in .Call("rs_createGD") : 
  C nombre de símbolo "rs_createGD" no está en la tabla de carga

Comment: Prueba `options(device = 'quartz') ` si es una MAC o `options(device = 'windows')` en Win o  `options(device = 'X11')` en Linux. Lo raro que bajo Rstudio debería funcionar `options(device = "RStudioGD")`

Comment: lo solucione actualizando Rstudio :)